# Connecting Reactjs to Myqtthub

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mqtt, iot

Hello I'm new to all this IOT thing and I want to be able to send and receive data from an Arduino via mqtt using https://myqtthub.com as our broker.  I used the following code in order to connect:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var options={
    clientId:"mqttjs01",
    username:"user",
    password:"password",
    clean:true};
    var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://node02.myqtthub.com",options)

client.on('connect', () => {
    alert('Connected!');
   
    console.log('Connected');
});




class Garage extends Component {
   
   
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>HEllooo</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Garage;
```

I'm having the error:
"WebSocket connection to 'ws://node02.myqtthub.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301"

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is all running in the browser (mainly because MQTT.js is forcing the connection to be over ws:// as that is the ONLY option in the browser).

Looking at the docs for myqtthub, they do NOT claim any support for MQTT over Websockets (and the [support](https://support.asplhosting.com/t/websockets-support/82) forum says they don't support it yet). This means your application will NOT work with this broker provider until they add Websockets support..

Comment: What broker do you suggest to use that will surely work in my case?

Comment: I can't answer that, I have no idea what the requirements are for your project.

Comment: Actually it's very simple, I have about 4 sensors installed somewhere and comnected to Arduino. The Arduino is sending data to an MQTT broker. I want to be able to publish messages and subscribe to topics. For testing I want a free brooer for now sonce the data is not very sensitive (Temperature sensors).

Answer (score 1):

Ugh....Where to start....

First off, go read the docs at https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js

You CONNECT, but you never SUBSCRIBE...not to mention you didn't post any code that you are PUBLISHing any data.  Your `client` can both send (PUBLISH) and receive (SUBSCRIBE) data, but you have to set them both up.

As for your initial problem, you didn't define the port to use on the connect.  You are also specifying `mqtt://` as the protocol, not `ws://`, so that will also cause you problems if you really do want a WebSocket connection. How you are getting that websocket error is a mystery, since your code example shows it to be using the MQTT protocol.

If you are just starting out, stick with `mqtt://` and work up from that.

Comment: Can you please provide me with how to define the port?

Comment: Just like any URL:   `mqtt://node02.myqtthub.com:1883/`

Comment: I did what you recommended now I'm getting a similar error :                                        \ ' WebSocket connection to 'ws://node02.myqtthub.com:1883/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response'

Comment: As hardillb says in his answer: If you are running this from inside a browser, your only option is WebSockets, which it looks like what you are trying to do, since it seems to be forced into `ws://` rather than `mqtt://` like in my example.  Those are two different protocols, which behave and are handled  very differently.