# Trying to debug the request sent form NodeRed project to myqtthub

Tags: mqtt, iot, node-red

It's my first time using node red and I'm trying to post a message to myqtthub and it's working fine. I'm trying to find a way to see the details of the request sent from node red to the mqtt broker. What I want to see is something like this:

```
{
  "protocol":"ws",
  "slashes":true,
  "auth":null,
  "host":"node02.myqtthub.com",
  "port":1883,
  "hostname":"node02.myqtthub.com",
  "hash":null,
  "search":"",
  "query":{},
  "pathname":null,
  "path":"/",
  "href":"mqtt://node02.myqtthub.com",
  "clientId":"idbj'",
  "username":"dddd",
  "password":"Qpasswwqordv",
  "defaultProtocol":"ws",
  "keepalive":60,
  "reschedulePings":true,
  "protocolId":"MQTT",
  "protocolVersion":4,
  "reconnectPeriod":1000,
  "connectTimeout":30000,
  "clean":true,
  "resubscribe":true,
  "wsOptions":{},
  "objectMode":false
}
```

This JSON object is provided from another project and I want to be able to see such Object for my request sent from this project.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Those detail look to be the client connection information, which you would enter into the MQTT Broker config node.

Comment: Exactly, however in the setup I only entered about five config inputs. I need the rest of the information. I need them because I'm trying to connect to the same mqtt broker but using React and I'm getting an error. So since it's working with node red I want the configuration so I can put them correctly in the React project.

Comment: In other words I'm trying to get an answer for my problem here: tinyurl.com/37untdwa

Comment: You do not need that information, it won't help you. I have answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274093/connecting-reactjs-to-myqtthub/66105041#66105041).